# Spring REST, Kotin and default primitive parameters leads to an error

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-rest

I get an error:

> Optional long parameter 'count' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type

when I try to invoke this REST controller.

```
    @RequestMapping("/api/audio/tracks", produces = arrayOf(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    interface SomeApi {


        @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(GET))
        fun list(@RequestParam("count", defaultValue = "10") count: Long): Any
    }
```

Does not spring look at `defaultValue`?

How to solve this kind of problem?

!Kotlin defaults do not work either

Comment: try to use Kotlin's default argument: count: Long = 10, instead of Spring's

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found solution in my situation:

The reason was because of an interface. When I placed `@RequestParam("count", required = false, defaultValue = "10")` in the implementation everything start working.